# Why does my buck converter output 6.55 V instead of 5 V?

Tags: buck, step-down

I'm trying to use the [LMR51420 Simple Switcher IC](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmr51420.pdf?ts=1672909520727&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FLMR51420) to step down my 20 V DC to 5 V DC.

I have this circuit which is the typical application circuit from the datasheet:
[image: circuit]

When I measure the voltage on the output with my multimeter, it says 6.55 V.
The voltage on R8 is 0.8 V but it should be 0.6 V according to the datasheet.

This is the output which should be 5V

2 V, 10 us per division:

[image: 1]

Also the output, 2 V, 200 us per division:

[image: 2]

Comment: Do you have an image of your layout/construction? Additionally, do you have an oscilloscope trace or any other way of determining whether that 6.55 V is a stable 6.55 V or some kind of oscillating value that averages at 6.55 V?

Comment: What's the load on your circuit?

Comment: Your inductance is 3 times the value shown in the datasheet, is there a reason for that?

Comment: @nanofarad I added two oscilloscope images

Comment: other than a LDO which should stepdown the 5V to 3.3V nothing else.

Comment: @greybeard Those are the values the datasheet shows for 5V, using those values I get 0.602V across R8. Datasheet picks 13.7k for R8 and then calculates R7 as 100.4k, uses 100k as closest standard value.

Comment: @greybeard according to the datasheet R8 = ((Vout-Vref)/(Vref))*R7 = ((5V-0.6V)/(0.6))*13.7k = 100.5k

Comment: @GodJihyo There is an equation in the datasheet on page 18 to calculate the Lmin value. I used this equation and got an Lmin of 25uH so I rounded it to 33uH.

Comment: What are the waveforms in your question? You need to specify what these waveforms mean (or relate to) in your question.

Comment: @Andyaka I added a short description

Comment: Can you point out where the 0 volt reference level is on those pictures?

Comment: @Andyaka The 0V is on the bottom line.

Comment: Sorry, but why does the box in the left corner say the offset is -8.00 volts? Have you tried adding a load to the output and seeing what happens?

Comment: You should also view the scope output when you have the probe tip grounded in case your scope probe is picking up ghosts.

Comment: Are you sure about your Lmin calculation?  The datasheet table 9-1 suggests that 10 uH would be an appropriate inductor value.  These parts do not have external compensation, so the output filter has to be in a certain range in order to have acceptable phase margin.

Comment: @Andyaka The offset says -8V because I shifted CH1 down by 8V so you can make the waveform bigger, so you can see it better. The 0V line is in the middle, but because of the -8V offset it is 4 divison further down (1 division = 2V). If I removed the offset the whole waveform would be 8V further up and the I'd have to reduce the vertical division,  which would make the waveform less readable.

Comment: Show us your PCB layout, and links to the exact inductor & capacitor you're using for L1 & C4.

Answer (score 2):

Web bench says you need a 12uH inductor with 25mOhm DCR. The output capacitor also needs to have low DCR. If you aren't using the reference layout, make sure the PCB traces have lower or equal resistance and inductance. Also check the vias and make sure they are not contributing too much inductance or resistance in the layout.

[image]